# Which audience was targeted by "Scarecrow and Mrs. King"?

Tags: analysis, scarecrow-and-mrs-king

"Scarecrow and Mrs. King" told the story of a divorced mom who accidentally meets a hunky secret agent and -- unbeknownst to her family and friends -- joins the secret agent on many spy adventures.

As a pre-teen viewer, I liked the show for its action and adventure, and I also had a boy's crush on Mrs. King (Kate Jackson). But more than 20 years later, I realize the show also seems to have offered an appealing escape fantasy to adult women, not to mention the cute capering of a former Charlie's Angel to adult men.

For a long time, I assumed "Scarecrow & Mrs. King" was aimed at kids, kind of like "A-Team" or "Knight Rider". But is that accurate? **Which audience was "Scarecrow and Mrs. King" trying to attract -- kids, adult women, adult men, or some combination of the three?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the audience desired was Nielsen Families. Really the three shows you described all had a target audience of families. In the 80's there were a lot of family shows that were trying to include action into their format. So most shows on during primetime were either an action family show or a family sitcom. This show really did attract a wide range of audience though. Having a former Charlie's Angel on attracted both men and women, a bored house wife appealed to women, the handsome secret agent pulled in women for the handsome and men and kids for the secret agent. Also kids and moms related to Mrs. King since she was a regular mom. Women could daydream they were Mrs. King men could daydream they were the secret agent and kids could daydream that their mom was a spy while they were at school.

Comment: Recall that at the time the series was aired, most American families had access to new programming on only thee networks; with few exceptions, programs tended to pursue broad audiences.